# Catalog Search looking at descriptions = returning irrelevant search results

Tags: catalogsearch, search

The Catalog Search seems to be returning irrelevant search results probably because it is searching also based on descriptions. What are the proper CATALOG SEARCH settings? Also - layered navigation seems to be connected with this somehow - what is layered navigation and how do I know if I have it or not?

Comment: Which magento are you using? `Community or Enterprise`? If Enterprise use `solar', it's very good.

Answer (score 5):

I too faced the same problem before.
This is because by default "description" attribute is set to Searchable.

**Solution:**

1. Login to Magento Admin Panel.
2. Goto **Catalog** > **Attributes** > **Manage Attributes**
3. Search for "description" attribute and edit it.
4. Change **Searchable** field to **NO**
5. Save it.
6. ReIndex data.
7. Clear Cache if required.

This should work. =)

Cheers!!

Comment: Also though this, but here in 2.4.3-p1 + sample data and on a custom store of the same version, it keeps indexing it even after this 